# A Fairly Simple Equation #2

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

I got a lot of positive feedback on my last puzzle, [A Fairly Simple Equation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72704/a-fairly-simple-equation) (even though it was apparently a lot easier than I thought it would be!) So, I've got another similar puzzle.

General Rules (Updated):

1. You must insert the given numbers into the given equation, each number replacing a letter in the equation, to get the given output.
2. You may not combine, invert, or reverse numbers. This doesn't have the lateral thinking tag for a reason.
3. Parentheses, or a number and parentheses, mean multiplication if they're put together like this: $(A+B)(C-D)$ or this $A(B+C)$
4. Rounding to the nearest whole number is allowed unless stated otherwise.
5. Reversal of the order of the numbers in an addition or multiplication is not counted as a separate answer. $(2+3)*4$ and $(3+2)*4$ are considered the same solution, for example.
6. The Order of Operations applies.

Specific #2 Rules:

1. The given numbers are, for this puzzle, $2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,$ and $11$.
2. Two of the given numbers will not be used.
3. The given output is $102$.
4. I could only find one answer, although it's definitely possible there may be more.

The Equation: $(A*(B+(C+D)*E))/(F/G)$

Good Luck!

Comment: Make sure to accept an answer if you think it is correct :)

Comment: To be extremely pedantic, it's not an equation but is an expression, since there's no equals sign to equate anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one:

> 2 3 6 5 9 8 4 for A-G respectively.

Strategy:

> I got a bit lucky. I set A=2 and F and G equal to 6 and 3, and then 8 and 4, so that they would cancel out and I had a simpler problem to solve. From there it was some simple guess-an-check to get the inner expression to equal 102.